# Detect when the noVolume option is being used with jPlayer

Tags: javascript, audio, jplayer

jPlayer has a [no volume option](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-noVolume) that is used on mobile devices (among others). I'm trying to locate how to check if the current player matches this setting or not? We'd like to add a class and change up the player if it's on a device that doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `status` information to determine this. As a (poor) example of this:

```
// initialize the player
$('.player').jPlayer({...});

// check if it has volume controls
if ($('.player').data('jPlayer').status.noVolume) {
  // does not have volume controls
}
```